# Python: Find If Substring Exists in String Given Condition

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures, string-search

I'm trying to optimize this solution for a function that accepts 2 arguments: `fullstring` and `substring`. The function will return `True` if the substring exists in the fullstring, and `False` if it does not. There is one special wildcard that could be entered in the substring that denotes 0 or 1 of the previous symbol, and there can be more than one wildcard in the substring.

For example, `"a*"` means `""` or `"a"`

The solution I have works fine but I'm trying to reduce the number of for loops (3) and optimize for time complexity. Using regex is not permitted. Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Current Solution:

```
def complex_search(fullstring, substring):
    patterns = []
    if "*" in substring:
        index = substring.index("*")
        patterns.append(substring[:index-1] + substring[index+1:])
        patterns.append(substring[:index] + substring[index+1:])
    else:
        patterns.append(substring)

    def check(s1, s2):
        for a, b in zip(s1, s2):
            if a != b:
                return False
        return True

    for pattern in patterns:
        for i in range(len(fullstring) - len(pattern) + 1):
            if check(fullstring[i:i+len(pattern)], pattern):
                return True
    return False

>> print(complex_search("dogandcats", "dogs*andcats"))
>> True
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a finite state machine?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no - I can look it up though

Comment: You could try using KMP for each possible string, which would be ```O(N*(2^X))``` where ```X``` is the number of wildcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

1. Create all alternatives for the substring based upon '*" in substring (can have zero or more '*' in substring)

   See Function combs(...) below
2. Use [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) to check if one of the substring patterns is in the string. Aho-Corasick is a very efficient algorithm for checking if one or more substrings appear in a string and formed as the basis of the original Unix command fgrep.
3. For illustrative purposes a Python version of Aho-Corasik is used below, but a C implementation (with Python wrapper) is available at [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/) for higher performance.

   See class Aho-Corasick below.

**Code**

```
# Note: This is a modification of code explained in https://carshen.github.io/data-structures/algorithms/2014/04/07/aho-corasick-implementation-in-python.html

from collections import deque

class Aho_Corasick():
    def __init__(self, keywords):
        self.adj_list = []
        # creates a trie of keywords, then sets fail transitions
        self.create_empty_trie()
        self.add_keywords(keywords)
        self.set_fail_transitions()

    def create_empty_trie(self):
        """ initalize the root of the trie """
        self.adj_list.append({'value':'', 'next_states':[],'fail_state':0,'output':[]})

    def add_keywords(self, keywords):
        """ add all keywords in list of keywords """
        for keyword in keywords:
            self.add_keyword(keyword)

    def find_next_state(self, current_state, value):
        for node in self.adj_list[current_state]["next_states"]:
            if self.adj_list[node]["value"] == value:
                return node
        return None

    def add_keyword(self, keyword):
        """ add a keyword to the trie and mark output at the last node """
        current_state = 0
        j = 0
        keyword = keyword.lower()
        child = self.find_next_state(current_state, keyword[j])
        while child != None:
            current_state = child
            j = j + 1
            if j < len(keyword):
                child = self.find_next_state(current_state, keyword[j])
            else:
                break

        for i in range(j, len(keyword)):
            node = {'value':keyword[i],'next_states':[],'fail_state':0,'output':[]}
            self.adj_list.append(node)
            self.adj_list[current_state]["next_states"].append(len(self.adj_list) - 1)
            current_state = len(self.adj_list) - 1
        self.adj_list[current_state]["output"].append(keyword)

    def set_fail_transitions(self):
        q = deque()
        child = 0
        for node in self.adj_list[0]["next_states"]:
           q.append(node)
           self.adj_list[node]["fail_state"] = 0
        while q:
            r = q.popleft()
            for child in self.adj_list[r]["next_states"]:
                q.append(child)
                state = self.adj_list[r]["fail_state"]
                while (self.find_next_state(state, self.adj_list[child]["value"]) == None
                      and state != 0):
                    state = self.adj_list[state]["fail_state"]
                self.adj_list[child]["fail_state"] = self.find_next_state(state, self.adj_list[child]["value"])
                if self.adj_list[child]["fail_state"] is None:
                    self.adj_list[child]["fail_state"] = 0
                self.adj_list[child]["output"] = self.adj_list[child]["output"] + self.adj_list[self.adj_list[child]["fail_state"]]["output"]

    def get_keywords_found(self, line):
        """ returns keywords in trie from line """
        line = line.lower()
        current_state = 0
        keywords_found = []

        for i, c in enumerate(line):
            while self.find_next_state(current_state, c) is None and current_state != 0:
                current_state = self.adj_list[current_state]["fail_state"]
            current_state = self.find_next_state(current_state, c)
            if current_state is None:
                current_state = 0
            else:
                for j in self.adj_list[current_state]["output"]:
                    yield {"index":i-len(j) + 1,"word":j}
    
    def pattern_found(self, line):
        ''' Returns true when the pattern is found '''
        return next(self.get_keywords_found(line), None) is not None
    
        
def combs(word, n = 0, path = ""):
    ''' Generate all combinations of words with star
    
        e.g. list(combs("he*lp*")) = ['help', 'helpp', 'heelp', 'heelpp']
    '''
    if n == len(word):
        yield path
    elif word[n] == '*':
        # Next letter
        yield from combs(word, n+1, path)            # don't add * to path
    else:
        if n < len(word) - 1 and word[n+1] == '*':
            yield from combs(word, n+1, path)        # Not including letter at n
        yield from combs(word, n+1, path + word[n])  # including letter at n
```

**Test**

```
patterns = combs("dogs*andcats")                    # ['dogandcats', 'dogsandcats']
aho = Aho_Corasick(patterns)                        # Aho-Corasick structure to recognize patterns
print(aho.pattern_found("dogandcats"))              # Output: True
print(aho.pattern_found("dogsandcats"))             # Output: True
```